# The identity $(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)=xx^T$ for a symmetric matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix with exactly 3 distinct eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$ and $\rho$, where $\rho$ is simple eigenvalue and $x$ is its eigenvector, then under which conditions the matrix identity from the title is valid?

It should hold if $A$ is non-negative and $\rho$ is the largest eigenvalue, but it seems that some modification can hold in other cases.

Comment: If $x$ is a unit-vector in this context, then the statement holds if and only if $(\rho - \lambda)(\rho-\mu) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the eigenvalue decomposition, then

\begin{align}(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)&=Q\begin{bmatrix} \rho-\lambda & & \\ & 0 & \\ & & \mu-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \rho-\mu & & \\ & \lambda - \mu & \\ & & 0\end{bmatrix} Q^T \\
&=Q\begin{bmatrix} (\rho-\lambda)(\rho-\mu) & & \\ &0 & \\ & & 0\end{bmatrix} Q^T  \\
&= (\rho-\mu)(\rho-\mu)q_1q_1^T\end{align}

We require $(\rho - \mu)(\rho - \mu) > 0$, hence $\rho$ is either the largest or the smallest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can verify it by noticing that
$$
(A-\mu I)(A-\lambda I) = (A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)
$$
and that, if $\{y,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, where $x$ is associated to $\rho$, and $v_i$ are associated to either $\lambda$ or $\mu$, then
$$
(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)v_i = (A-\mu I)(A-\lambda I)v_i =  0,
$$
$$
 (A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)y = (\rho - \lambda)(\rho-\mu)y.
$$
If now $x= \sqrt{(\rho - \lambda)(\rho-\mu)} y$, then $(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I) = xx^T$.

NOTICE: This holds even if $(\rho - \lambda)(\rho-\mu)<0$, only $A$ will not be positive semidefinite

Comment: This answer is confusing. "Under which conditions is the matrix identity from the title valid" is not a yes/no question.  From the context, it appears that $x$ is meant to be a vector with real entries so that your statement "this holds even if $(\rho - \lambda)(\rho - \mu) < 0$" is at best misleading.

Comment: "but it seems that some modification can hold in other cases." so I explained what modification are needed. The NOTICE is referred to the other answer

Comment: that's good but doesn't address either of my concerns

Comment: Sorry for confusing question: I should say that $A$ is a Hermitian matrix. We may say that, under assumptions on number of distinct eigenvalues and multiplicity of $\rho$, $(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)=xx^T$ holds for some (not necessarily unit) eigenvector afforded by $\rho$ iff $\rho$ is the largest or the least eigenvalue. And $(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)=-xx^T$ iff $\rho$ is neither the largest or the least eigenvalue (this would address ''some modification can hold in other cases''). Am I right? What if we have 4 eigenvalues, again one being simple?